# Why is maven looking for an artifact in the lib directory other than the one I'm running it with?

Tags: java, linux, maven, jvm, ubuntu-13.10

I'm trying to run clean install on a maven project of mine using JDK 1.6.0_**45** on a machine running Ubunto 13.10, but it fails with the error:

"Could not find artifact sun.plugin:plugin:jar:1.6 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_**41**/jre/lib/plugin.jar"

For some reason it's is trying to find the plugin in the wrong version of JDK, it's looking in update 41 directory(/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_**41**), which doesn't exist, instead of the update 45 directory. I've successfully ran clean install on another machine running Windows with jdk1.6.0_45

I've run a file search on my project but it didn't come up with any match for jdk1.6.0_**41**

Comment: You have messed up java installation in that mechine

Comment: I don't see how that could have happened. I downloaded the .bin file from the oracle site and executed it in the use/lib/jvm/ directory via the terminal. Was I doing something wrong? I'm new to linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following entry to your `~/.mavenrc`;

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/right/jdk
```

Or globally describe `JAVA_HOME` on your system by adding it to `~/.bashrc` (This will affect only your user)

Comment: It's already executing with the right version of the jdk I can see that in the console

Comment: Wht is the output of `mvn -v`

Comment: Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/jre
Default locale: en_ZA, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.11.0-15-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: Ok, one point left. Check your pom.xml, maybe you specified jdk version in pom.xml

Comment: You only specify a major version, not a minor version. So that has no effect on this problem, which I agree is kind of odd. At this point I'd probably do a grep search on jdk1.6.0_41 to see if it is referenced in some hidden configuration file somewhere.